# Finding distance between lines in 3D

Tags: calculus, 3d

Find the distance between the lines $L1$ and $L2$ where $$L1: \frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-2}{-3}=\frac{z-3}{4}$$ and $$L2: \frac{x+1}{3}=3-y=\frac{z+5}{5}$$

I need to first show that the lines are skew and not parallel.

I'm not sure how to approach this, any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: I would first put the lines in parametric form (by setting each of the two equations above equal to $t$ and solving for $x,y,z$). Next, two lines are parallel if and only if their tangent vectors are parallel. Lastly, point $p$ on line $l_1$ and point $q$ on line $l_2$ are the closest pair of points if the segment $pq$ is orthogonal to both lines.

Answer (score 2):

$t=\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-2}{-3}=\frac{z-3}{4}$ gives $x=1+2t, y=2-3t, z=3+4t$. That is
$L_1 = \{ (1,2,3)+t (2,-3,4) \}_t$.

$s=\frac{x+1}{3}=3-y=\frac{z+5}{5}$ gives $x=-1+3s, y=3-s, z=5s-5$. That is
$L_2 = \{ (-1,3,-5)+s(3,-1,5)\}_s$.

Hence the distance (squared to avoid roots) between a point on either line is given by
$$\|(1,2,3)+t (2,-3,4) - ((-1,3,-5)+s(3,-1,5)) \|^2 = \| ( 2+2t-3s  , -1-3t+s  , 8+4t-5s  ) \|^2$$,
which evaluates (assuming I made no mistakes) to
$29\,{t}^{2}-58\,s\,t+78\,t+35\,{s}^{2}-94\,s+69$.
Differentiating with respect to $s,t$ and setting to zero gives
$-58\,t+70\,s-94 = 0$, $58\,t-58\,s+78 = 0 $, and solving
yields $s={4 \over 3}, t= -{1 \over 87}$. The corresponding distance is ${16 \sqrt{2} \over \sqrt{87} }$.

An alternative approach could be based on the fact that the vector $(11,-2,-7)$ is perpendicular to the directions of both lines.

As a check I solved for $s,t$ such that the difference between the corresponding points lines up with the vector of the last paragraph, and the $s,t$ values are the same, so any errors are in the first few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** The denominators are direction ratios of the lines. They must be proportional if they are parallel.

I am sure you know the formula for skew lines.